# Select element onChange event is not firing in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 (javascript)

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to add an select element with onChange event to be fired with a javascript function.
I have the following code

```
<select asp-for="CardTypeId" 
        asp-items="..."
        class="selectpicker form-control" size="1"
        onchange="cardTypeId_OnChange">
    <option selected="selected">Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
</select>   

<script>

    function cardTypeId_OnChange() {

        alert('cardTypeId_OnChange');
    }

</script>
```

In this example i want that onchange to fire the cardTypeId_OnChange javascript function, and to not fire a function in server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function by onchange="cardTypeId_OnChange()" not onchange="cardTypeId_OnChange"